# Chromecast DAI stream doesn't start sometimes with the error

Tags: chromecast, google-cast-sdk, shaka, google-ima

We have an app with casting functionality for Google DAI stream. It works fine mainly, but recently, we started getting complaints that the stream doesn't start sometimes. The problem is that we didn't change any of our code for the receiver part, and I can't get what the issue is precisely or how to debug it further.

We can see
*[cast.player.hls.iterator] No match was
found using sequence number*

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
property 'ia'
undefined*
in the console - please see the attached screenshot.

How it looks on the screen: in 90% of cases, the stream just starts, but in 10% of cases, the stream can't start, and this log appears in the console. I can stop the stream and start it again, which starts normally.

Can't attach the inline screenshot - the URL is https://ibb.co/68vxL8Q